# Delphi components to use with SQlite

Tags: delphi, sqlite, components

What components can I use to use SQlite database with Delphi 6?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222699/which-embedded-database-to-use-in-a-delphi-application might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Zeos Library at http://zeos.firmos.at/portal.php.

It works well with SQLite and others.

It is free and you get the source code too.

Answer (score 7):

My Answer is AnyDAC in this case. We here currently use it and it works. Especially when you think that you get more than just what the database can do.
http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/

Comment: Great article about AnyDAC and SQLite - http://www.da-soft.com/blogs/developing-delphi-applications-with-sqlite-and-anydac.html

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [DISQLite3](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlite3/index) in FeedDemon and recommend it highly.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully used ASqlite from http://www.aducom.com.

It's free, open source software.

Answer (score 3):

The new [DevArt UniDac](http://www.devart.com/news/2009/unidac270b.html) components has Sqlite provider

[Unidac](http://www.devart.com/unidac/) isn't free, but it's highly recommend and has very stable and fast providers, support Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySql, Interbase,PostgreSql and now Sqlite.

Comment: I hate it when down vote for correct answer, without giving any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

We just validated our Synopse SQlite3 framework for Delphi 6.

You've got a whole Client/Server ORM framework, using SQLite3 3.7.3 for its data storage.
It's fast and light. And there is some User-Interface dedicated classes (Screen auto-generation, reporting with direct pdf export...).

See http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=2

Comment: I've extracted the SQLite3 wrapper out of the ORM. And you have even an abstract DB layer, so that you can change later to any other database engine, if needed, just by changing the class type used. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/22/SynDBSQLite3%3A-SQLite3-direct-access

Answer (score 2):

I use [LiteDAC](http://www.devart.com/litedac/) (components for SQLite by Devart) and like it much, because It allows to link the SQLite library statically into your application and has built-in SQlite encryption! So I recommend it highly

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi XE7, FireDAC was integrated into Delphi.

[Embarcadero purchased DA-SOFT in 2013](http://www.embarcadero.com/press-releases/embarcadero-technologies-acquires-high-performance-enterprise-database-connectivity-technology-for-developers), and FireDAC is their renamed AnyDAC.

Embarcadero plans to support and continue development of FireDAC, so it is now an excellent choice to be your Data Access Component for SQLite.

Comment: But the questioner asked about using Sqlite with Delphi 6, which pre-dates FireDAC by a long way

Comment: @MartynA - Wouldn't this be a useful answer to have here for other people who come across this question but have XE7 or later?

Comment: I guess so, but owners of XE7+ wouldn't have to look much further than the OLH.  I'll have to remind myself of the Sqlite driver I used with D7 and maybe add it to the list if it's not already there.