# How Do SQLite and DISQLite Compare for a Large Simple Database?

Tags: delphi, sqlite, embedded-database

What are the differences between [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and [DISQLite](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlite3/index) and why would I want to pick one over the other?

My context is that I am dealing with a large database (could be up to 10 GB), the critical part of which is in one very simple table with a single indexed field and one text field up to a few KB in size.  My development tool is Delphi 2009 and the database will be embedded in my .exe.

My main criteria is speed. This would be for a software application running on a typical Windows computer, say with Windows 7 and 4 GB of RAM.

If you want to suggest another database tool, please tell me why it would be better than these two for my application, especially on the speed frontier.

Comment: You mean the database *engine* (not the database file itself) will be embedded in the executable, right?

Comment: Yes. The database is still disk-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIR, DISQLite uses the obj files of Sqlite, and compile them with Delphi and produce more features than the original one, and using the same sqlite DB format, hence you can read the DISQLite database file by it by other languages that has support for Sqlite drivers.

Also one more feature with DISQLite you don't have to distribute the Sqlite DLL.

DISQLite support database size up to 2TB, so it could handle your requires without problems.

Another options I would consider is FireBird embedded version,and if you would like to scale it more, you can change to full FireBird server without much effort.

But I think both Sqlite & DISQLite will perform better than Firebird.

I use [Audcom Sqlite components](http://www.aducom.com/cms/news.php) to access Sqlite databases, and you can compile it with Sqlite objs file so you will not have deploy sqlite dll.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion of them performing better than Firebird. But as Kavitesh says, SQLite can be compiled into my application with the sourcecode and no DLL is required.

Comment: From SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
The sqlite-amalgamation provides all preprocessed C code combined into a single source file which can be used in your application and compiled together.
Since i have not worked on delphi, so i would not comment if it can compile C code directly or would require DLL to access all the APIs.

Comment: He meant the source code of original sqlite library, which is written in C, If you read last paragraph in my answer, you can do that with Audcom Sqlite components too, so you don't have to distribute the Sqlite Dll with your application.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you writing your own implementation. If you don't need complex SQL queries, the simplest (and probably the fastest) implementation is file-based storage.

Comment: I've thought about that idea for awhile. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799634/how-should-i-implement-a-huge-but-simple-indexed-stringlist-in-delphi

Comment: I agree, actually fastest performance on sequential reading/writing...but horrible access on random reading.  If you need indexed access on large datasets then use an engine...if the sets are relatively small, or only read in the order they are written then use a file/stream based solution.

Answer (score 1):

DISQLLite has two versions with the free one limited to personal and non-commerical usage. So this could be one of the deciding factor as SQLite is free opensource implementation without free/paid versions.

Both of the database would be able to handle data ranging in GBs. SQLite is available in pre-compiled binary i.e. DLL which can be distributed along your application. However, with the source code available you can also compile it within your application and use it without the need for DLL.

The advantage of using the DLL module (at times) is when some of the bugs are resolved you would simply be required to replace the DLL at the client machine instead of recompiling the whole application.

I feel SQLite would be a better option for yor requirement. Speed of database is not entirely based on the type of database. Hardware like harddisk access speed, available processing power, RAM etc also play an important role in speeding up database.

Comment: But WHY do you think would SQLite be better for me? I know speed depends on outside factors, but for standard windows machines running Vista or Windows 7 with 4GB RAM, which would be better for me (I'll add this to my question as well).

Comment: SQLite is opensource with no limitations whatsover. If you check the comparison chart for DISqlite http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlite3/feature_chart?DokuWiki=t5fl5li3pqncsusi0qd0df90m3 you would see most of the features are available in paid version. Also since you are not looking at enterprise level db, the performance difference would be negligible i feel. Also right now DISQLite offers free version, they might discontinue or offer it at some price later on. Which may be a prob. Also SQLite is having active community development making updates easily available.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the DISQLLite personal version has some limitations and I don't think that the price for the professional version (Euro 149.99 without source) is worth it when anyone can just implement a SQLite wrapper for free.

I was using DISQLite personal for a freeware product and had to implement a database change in a new version release. The personal version does not support 'ALTER' so I was faced with having to purchase the full version. So I ditched DISQLite and just went with a good SQLite wrapper. Only go for DISQLite if you're prepared to pay for the full version.

[SQLite4Delphi](http://sqlite4delphi.sourceforge.net/) might be a better option, or at least point you to a more cost-effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at our [SynBigTable unit](http://blog.synopse.info/category/Open-Source-Projects/Synopse-BigTable). It's will be [much faster than SQLite](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=1011#p1011), and seems to fit exactly your purpose.

And if you need a native SQLite implementation, take a look at our [SQLite3 framework](http://blog.synopse.info/category/Open-Source-Projects/SQLite3-Framework): it's free and OpenSource, without any external dll. And has some more features than the closed DiSQLite (like Delphi native classes for implementing SQL functions or Virtual tables).

For the performance POV, the bottleneck won't be the wrapper you're using, but the disk access, and how you set up your database. Don't forget to use [indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) to retrieve your data as fast as possible. Then even 10 GB of data won't be a problem for SQLite, whatever wrapper you are using.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Although it isn't the answer to my question, I'm very impressed by what I'm reading about SynBigTable, and it may just be the module I need for my program that I've been looking for. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799634/how-should-i-implement-a-huge-but-simple-indexed-stringlist-in-delphi I picked GpStructuredStorage for that, but (without testing first) it seems like SynBitTable might be better for me.

Comment: @lkessler I just quoted about SynBigTable, because there is never a closed question in Software. Sometimes, it's better to change it's first intend (e.g. changing the storage engine of an architecture). Nerver close all doors. ;)

Comment: @lkessler You asked about SQlite on Delphi, and there is just not only DiSQLite around - there are several wrappers, and from my own (trolling) POV, I don't like the fact that you should have to pay for using an OpenSource library. That's what I tried to do my best to release an OpenSource SQLite3 wrapper which is free, fast, light, and Delphi friendly. My unit has high-level Delphi class-oriented wrappers for SQLite3 features than DiSQLite3 do not support, like custom SQL functions or virtual tables. Virtual tables is just a gem of SQLite3. ;)

Comment: We just made our SQLite3 wrapper independent from our ORM, in a new dedicated unit. You have access to any OleDB providers (including latest version of MSSQL), Oracle via direct access to the OCI layer 
and now SQLite3, statically embedded to the executable. You can change from one DB to the other, with a small code overhead. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/22/SynDBSQLite3%3A-SQLite3-direct-access