# I need some info about dBase field types

Tags: delphi, dbase, tdbf

I need to store an array of words and bytes (and some other data) in a TDBF database (this DB is compatible with dBase). But I don't know the meaning of the field types this DB is using. For example what can I store in a file of 'Array' type or 'TypedBinary'?
From where I can get some dBase IV documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the constants used by TDBF are actually defined in DB.PAS (borland). It seems that TDBF is not so compatible with dBase.

Update: Due to lack of documentation I abandoned the TDBF library .

Comment: The base subset of DBF is mostly based on older dBases (specifically dbase3). Later newer dBases and drivers from other vendors (like Borland) try to extend this base subset in various incompatible ways