# What are the simplest database types which I can use with ADO?

Tags: sql-server, database, delphi, ado, delphi-xe2

I'm looking for a way that I can keep a database in one single file, no server hosting it, and with the ability to use ADO (In delphi, specifically `TADOConnection` and/or `TADOQuery`). Please pardon my lack of terminology on this one. I'm only familiar with SQL Server databases, and nothing about any others. In fact, the only other ways I know to read/write files are Plain Text, INI, and XML. As for any official "databases", I know nothing.

So what I would like to do is keep a single file as a database, similar to how QuickBooks has a single "Company File". I should not have anything to host the data, such as SQL Server. And it needs to be compatible with ADO, so I can use simple `select`, `update`, `delete`, etc. It doesn't need to be so complex as to have relations, security, etc. But it does need to have some same syntax rules as SQL Server, like commands such as `join`, `alter`, `distinct`, etc.

I'm looking for the lightest-weight method to do so. The files need to be flexible enough to be able to copy/paste (so long as the application isn't using it), similar to an excel file. In fact, my original idea was to use Excel, as I know I can use ADO, but I also don't want to require Microsoft's excel drivers (it would have to presume that MS Office / Excel is installed on user's computer). It's obviously going to need some drivers, but I need the most standard method which is compatible everywhere.

Comment: Why require ADO? If you eliminate that requirement it opens up other options, like SQLite.

Comment: Because we already have 16 years worth of code using ADO components

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222699/which-embedded-database-to-use-in-a-delphi-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options for store your data in single database file.

- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html)
- [`Firebird`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/start/)
- [Interbase](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/interbase)

All of them can be accesed via ADO using a ODBC or OLEDB driver. my personal recomendation is Firebird, because is free, fast, stable and had a [`Embedded`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html) version.

Comment: Found this question, by the way... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78621/what-do-i-need-to-start-using-embedded-firebird-with-delphi

Answer (score 7):

You can use `MS-Access` MDB files. It can be used via Microsoft `OLEDB Jet 4` engine (Which is build in into Windows since at least Win XP) and is perfect for local desktop DB applications, with the ability to create Tables, PKs, Indexes, Queries/Views, Transactions, Multi-User, replication, compact/repair and much more  with almost perfect compatibility to `MS SQL-Server` SQL syntax (since `MS-Access` is the ancestor of `MS SQL-Server`).
`MS-Access` product (i.e `MS Office`) **dose not** have to be installed on the client machine. 
No extra drivers or files to install, and completely integrable with existing MS-Office products.

---

Edit: MDB files could be also [Protected/Encrypted](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-HA010096299.aspx).

Comment: If you want the users to also be able to open the database and link to it from Excel or mailmerge, Access is certainly recommended!

Comment: Access is great as long as you understand its [limitations](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/access_specification.php)

Comment: I'm actually trying not to use Access, because 1) it has way more than I need, and 2) If anything I do not want anyone to open this database themselves to look at it. Using access makes this way too easy, I want to make it difficult for the end user to see the raw data.

Comment: @JerryDodge, MDB files can be protected/encrypted with username + password. Having "more than I need" is better than having less ;) In the end it's your choice... I'm not working for MS.

Comment: To rephrase what I meant, Access is too easy to work with, it's designed for people who don't know or want to know how to write code. It's kinda like a beefed up excel.

Comment: @JerryDodge, You are completely wrong. It is *nothing* like Excel, and has nothing to do with `Access.Application` (Building DB applications *with* Access) . You will use MS-Access to build your DB structure and DB design. Once you have done it, you have a single MDB file, and it's all with Delphi/ADO from now on...

Comment: ^^ Metaphorically speaking, I wasn't serious

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://sql-db.cz.cc/) is a pretty useful comparison of a number of embedded databases. Of the ones tested these ones support (odbc), (oledb)  or (both) and use a (single) file for the database:

- Accuracer (odbc) (single)
- NexusDB (odbc) (single v4 and newer)
- Firebird (both) (single) - multiple odbc implementations and the commercial IBProvider supports three different ways to connect to the ADO components.
- TurboDB (odbc) (single v4 and newer)

Note: Most of these also supply ADO.Net Providers as well.

The other's in the comparison (Advantage, ElevateDB, DBISAM and Apollo) use a file per table/index scheme.